# How does % function that is used in a Path

Tags: powershell, path, pki

I am setting up a PKI with a script but I have some lines here that I don't understand how it works

Script uses in some paths for example "http://pseudo.domain.org/%3%8%9.crl" .

But the script creates this file with a real name for example pseudo domain.crl

How exactly does the %3%8%9.crl etc become the file name?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $HttpCdp = "http://pseudo.domain.org/%3%8%9.crl" that the variable.  
Thats the Script Path
# Adding our own CDP Configuration
Add-CaCrlDistributionPoint -uri "$($CertEnrollFolder)\%3%8%9.crl" -PublishToServer -PublishDeltaToServer -Force
If ($HttpCdp) {
    Add-CaCrlDistributionPoint -uri $HttpCdp -AddToCertificateCDP -Force
}
If ($LdapCdp) {
    Add-CaCrlDistributionPoint -uri $LdapCdp -AddToCrlCdp -AddToCertificateCDP -Force

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The escape sequence `%XX` (where `X` are hexadecimal digits) is known as [percent-encoding or URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

In a URI, some characters, like `:` or `/` or `@` for example, have special syntactical meaning, and so they need to be escaped if passed as part of a path.

You can manually escape parts of a URI string with `[uri]::EscapeDataString()`:

```
PS C:\> $path = "uri-stem-with-a-@-in-it"
PS C:\> [uri]::EscapeDataString($path)
uri-stem-with-a-%40-in-it
```

To decode an encoded string, use `[uri]::UnescapeDataString()`:

```
PS C:\> [uri]::UnescapeDataString("%41%42%43")
ABC
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and the fast help!

Comment: Keine Ursache! :)